# AWS Rekognition PHP SDK gives invalid image encoding error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

I am using the PHP SDK to upload a local file (not S3) to be parsed in AWS Rekognition. However, the image blob will not work and I get the message: `InvalidImageFormatException: "Invalid image encoding"`.

I've tried multiple images ([the docs say JPEGs and PNGs are accepted](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/rekognition/latest/dg/API_DetectLabels.html)), but none work.

My code is:

```
$client = new RekognitionClient($credentials);

$im = file_get_contents('/app/image1.png');
$imdata = base64_encode($im);

$result = $client->detectLabels(
    [
       'Image' => [
          'Bytes' => $imdata,
       ]
    ]
);
```

Am I encoding it correctly? The [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Image.html) are quite vague.

I've found SO questions about 'No Image Content', but none about invalid format.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Check that base64_encode() doesn't return FALSE. Also, try old style array:  detectLabels(array('Image'=>array('Bytes'=>$imdata)))

Comment: @SergeyKovalev Yep, `base64_encode()` does return the data as expected, and unfortunately changing the array style didn't work either :/

Comment: What if you skip `base64_encode()` part?

Comment: You should not be using base64_encode(). It works without it.

Comment: @nibty Then what do I pass to the request? Nothing works except an Imagick blob?

Comment: I send the the data directly from file_get_contents(). I'm using the same code as you but passing $im directly as Bytes. It's worked so far with the handful of jpgs I've used. Can you share one of the images you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) rather than the `base64_encode` route. I suspect this isn't the best way, but it does work great!

```
$client = new RekognitionClient($credentials);

$image = new Imagick('/app/image1.png');
$imdata = $image->getImageBlob();

$result = $client->detectLabels(
    [
       'Image' => [
          'Bytes' => $imdata,
       ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: You don't need any library to do that. It's exactly the same as just calling `file_get_contents('/app/image1.png')`.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should not apply base64 encoding. SDK does it for blobs.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Api/Serializer/JsonBody.php:

```
        case 'blob':
            return base64_encode($value);
```

Comment: I've not been able to get this to work, it gives the same error for me...

Comment: Looks like the docs are confusing. They should say "you can't" instead of "may not need to".

Answer (score 1):

```
    $s3 = new \Aws\Rekognition\RekognitionClient([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'BKxxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'GYxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        ]
    ]);

    $result = $s3->detectLabels([
        'Image' => [ // REQUIRED
            'Bytes' => file_get_contents("http://img13.deviantart.net/5a3b/i/2010/249/b/a/__michelangelo__s_flying_horse___by_dark_oak_trails-d2y5iej.jpg"),
        ],
        'MaxLabels' => 10,
        'MinConfidence' => 90,
    ]);
```

You **don't need** to base64_enconde the image when using their SDK.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_Image.html

> Your code may not need to encode image bytes if you are using an AWS SDK...